# cordova platform add android not working, how can compile using cordova? Ionic project

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm running this line command

> cordova platform add android

To start compiling the app APK, but the following error appears on the command line

[image]

I don't understand why the cordova command isn't working, what could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if its not already done, to run this command first :

```
ionic cordova prepare android
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-prepare

otherwise, try renaming the android folder, run and the prepare command again. some people experienced the same issue and this work-around worked
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/could-not-install-from-ios-as-it-does-not-contain-a-package-json-file/168462/5